# What is the unit of row height in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

In Microsoft Excel, Row Height is set as 15. What is the unit of 15? Is it inches, centimeters, etc.? I am trying to compare the height of the rows to a sheet of paper before I print it out.

Comment: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/excel-row-height-units-t1027501.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in points. 72 points = 1 inch.

Answer (score 5):

72 points (DPI) = 1 inch = 96 pixels; 
Column width:
8.43 characters =64 pixels;
Row Height:
15 points = 20 pixels.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Points aren't DPI, not all screens are 96 PPI, not all pixels are square, and there is not a fixed relationship between pixels and characters.